# Scrapy: send post in script way without Spider

Tags: python, scrapy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy


def errback(failure):
    print(failure)

def callback(response):
    print(response)


scrapy.FormRequest(r'https://example.com',
                   callback=callback,
                   errback=errback)
```

In the script above, neither errback nor callback is called.

What is the simplest way to send a post request to `https://example.com` using scrapy in python3. I'd like to avoid using a Spider class/object if possible.

Answer (score 1):

use `requests`

`pip3 install requests`

```
import requests

url = "[url]"

payload = {}
headers = {
  #Headers here
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. My other code already uses scrapy. I want to check if scrapy can do the post..

Comment: Ah sorry misunderstood the request.